# Datatables columnDefs doesn't work with multiple tables

Tags: php, html, datatable, datatables

I have an HTML file that has Bootstrap Tab generated by PHP according to the amount saved in the database,

And with that I also generated a corresponding table in each Tab, and in turn generate the script of this table dynamically by PHP using a foreach.

In the datables Script there are several table functions that work on all tables created in each Tab, but the columnDefs function only works for the first table displayed on the Tab as Active.

Obs.: In some tests in the browser, I noticed that if I activate the mobile mode being in a Tab that had not worked the columnDefs, it works correctly, but it stops working in the Tab that was working previously.

Below is the code snippet

```
<?php if($companys): ?>
    <div class="card-header p-0 border-bottom-0">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="custom-tabs-four-tab" role="tablist">
            <?php $c = 0 ?? NULL ?>
            <?php foreach($companys as $company): ?>                                                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link <?= $c == 0 ? "active" : ""?>" id="company_<?= $company->id ?>_tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#company_<?= $company->id ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="company_<?= $company->id ?>" aria-selected="true"><?= $company->name ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php $c++ ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($companys): ?>
    <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-four-tabContent">
        <?php $c = 0 ?? NULL ?>
        <?php foreach($companys as $company): ?>
            <div class="tab-pane fade <?= $c == 0 ? "show active" : ""?>" id="company_<?= $company->id ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="company_<?= $company->id ?>_tab">
                        
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-sm">
                        <table id="listEmployees_<?= $company->id ?>" class="table table-sm table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Employee</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                    <th>...</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php if($closureList): ?>                                                                
                                    <?php foreach((array) $closureList as $closure): ?>
                                        <?php if($closure->id_company == $company->id): ?>
                                        <tr>                                        
                                            <td><?= str_title_case($closure->name_employee); ?></td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                            <td>...</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>       
                </div> 

            </div>                            
        <?php $c++ ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        <?php if($companys): ?>
            <?php foreach($companys as $company): ?>
                $('#listEmployees_<?= $company->id ?>').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "searching": true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info": true,
                    //"autoWidth": true,
                    "responsive": false,
                    "scrollX": true,     
                    //"scrollY": "300px",         
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "pageLength": 25,    
                    "columnDefs": [
                        { width: 200, targets: 0 },
                        { width: 70, targets: 1 },
                        { width: 70, targets: 2 },
                        { width: 70, targets: 3 },  
                        { width: 95, targets: 4 },
                        { width: 60, targets: 6 }                          
                    ],
                    "fixedColumns": true,             
                    "buttons": [
                        //Excel
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            title: 'Closure_<?= $referenceMonth ?>'
                        },
                    ]           
                }).buttons().container().appendTo('#listEmployees_<?= $company->id ?>_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

"The reason this requires special consideration is that when the DataTable is initialised in a hidden element the browser doesn't have any measurements with which to give the DataTable, and this will result in the misalignment of columns when scrolling is enabled.

This misalignment can be corrected by the columns.adjust() method when the table is made visible (i.e. it has dimensions)."

To fix your issue, you just need to add below code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       
    $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
} );
```

This will do the column width adjustment on clicking the tabs.